# How to get the "x highest value" in mysql

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am still a beginner in Java and stackoverflow.

I coded a plugin for a minecraft server in java, using mysql for a stats system (Kills deaths points)

I want to know, how i can get the player with the highest amount of "Points", so i like to get the "Playername" where "Points" is the highest.
I also would like to get the 2nd highest, 3rd highest etc.

I used prepared statements like:

```
public static int getPoints(String Playername) {
    int Points = 0;
    try {
        PreparedStatement st = con
                .prepareStatement("SELECT Points FROM FFA WHERE UUID = '"
                        + PlayerUtil.getUUID(Playername) + "'");
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();
        if (rs.next()) {
            Points = rs.getInt("Points");
        } else {
            Points = 0;
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return Points;
}
```

If you are able to help me, that would be extremely nice! 
Thanks for your time!

PS:
My SQL structure:

```
Playername varchar(64)
UUID varchar(64)
Kills int
Deaths int
Points int
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following statement to do that:

```
select playername from FFA order by points desc limit 10;
```

That will return the top 10 players

Or you could do something like

```
select playername from FFA where points >= 1337 order by points DESC;
```

Then you can go through every entry calling `rs.next()` in a loop. First fetch with `rs.next()` will get you the player with more points because you used `order by`.

So the code would look like this:

```
public static String getTopPlayer() {
    int limit = 10;

    try {
            preparedstatement st = con 
                    .preparestatement("select * from FF order by points desc limit "
                                    + limit);
            resultset rs = st.executequery();
            if (rs.next()) {
                    name = rs.getString("playername");
                    //if rs.next() rs.getString("playername"); <-- returns second
                    //if rs.next(); rs.getString("playername"); <-- returns third
            } else {
                    name = null;
            }   
    } catch (sqlexception e) {
            e.printstacktrace();
    }
    return name;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this in SQL :

```
select playername from FFA where points=(select max(points) from FFA);
```

This query can return more than one row...